# HTTP: Combining expiration and validation caching

Tags: http, caching, conditional-statements, http-caching

I'm having trouble formulating HTTP cache headers for the following situation.

Our server has large data that changes perhaps a couple times a week. I want browsers to cache this data. Additionally, I want to minimize latency from conditional gets as the network is unreliable.

The end behavior I'm after is this:

1. Client requests a resource it hasn't seen before.
2. Server responds with resource along with ETag and `max-age` (24 hours).
3. Until 24 hours has passed, client will use cached resource.
4. After the expiration date, client will perform a validate request (`If-None-Match: [etag]`)
5. If resource has not changed:

   - server responds with `304 Not Modified`
   - **client is somehow informed that the existing resource has a new expiration date 24 hours from now**
   - return to step 3

Boiled down to its essense... can a 304 response contain a new `max-age`? Or is the original `max-age` honored for subsequent requests?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, a 304 response can contain a new `max-age` (or ETag, or other response headers for that matter).

I did an experiment using Firefox 4 to test whether the original max-age or the new one is honored, and the answer was that the new `max-age` is honored, so you should be able to implement what you want to do.

It's important to remember that `max-age` is relative to the `Date` response header, not `Last-Modified`, so whenever your server sets a `max-age` directive of 24 hours, it is saying "24 hours from right now." So, assuming that's what you want, you won't have to change your `max-age` at all, just always return 86400.

Anyway, here's an overview and dump of my experiment. Basically, I hit a test URL that set an ETag and set `max-age` to 120 seconds. Accordingly, the server returned the page with these response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 14 Jun 2011 23:48:51 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=120
Etag: "901ea3d0ac9303ae4855a09676f96701"
Last-Modified: Mon, 13 Jun 2011 22:20:03 GMT
```

I then repeated hitting "enter" in the address bar to load the page (but not force a hard reload). There was no network traffic, since Firefox repeatedly reloaded the page from cache. Then, after 120 seconds were over, the very next time I hit enter, Firefox instead sent a conditional GET to the server, as you would expect. The request and response from the server were:

```
GET /example HTTP/1.1
If-Modified-Since: Mon, 13 Jun 2011 22:20:03 GMT
If-None-Match: "901ea3d0ac9303ae4855a09676f96701"

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Tue, 14 Jun 2011 23:50:54 GMT
Etag: "901ea3d0ac9303ae4855a09676f96701"
Cache-Control: max-age=240
```

Note that in the 304 response, I've had the server change `max-age` from 120 seconds to 240.

So, the big question is, what would happen after 120 seconds? Would Firefox respect the new `max-age` and continue loading the page from cache, or would it hit the server? The answer is that it continued loading the page from cache, and did not re-request until after 240 seconds were reached:

```
GET /example HTTP/1.1
If-Modified-Since: Mon, 13 Jun 2011 22:20:03 GMT
If-None-Match: "901ea3d0ac9303ae4855a09676f96701"

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Tue, 14 Jun 2011 23:54:56 GMT
Etag: "901ea3d0ac9303ae4855a09676f96701"
Cache-Control: max-age=240
```

I repeated through another 240-second cycle and things worked as you'd expect. So, hopefully that answers the question for you.

The [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) explains how age computations are supposed to be implemented, and how the other Cache-Control parameters work. There's no guarantee that every browser and proxy will follow the rules, but at this point HTTP 1.1 is pretty old and you'd expect most of them will do as Firefox does.

(**Note:** For brevity in these example dumps, I've deleted irrelevant headers such as host, connection/keep-alive, content encoding/length/type, user-agent etc.)

Comment: "I then repeated hitting "enter" in the address bar to load the page (but not force a hard reload)." -- This was the key piece of info I needed to do the experiment myself! Thanks for the well-researched answer!

Comment: I repro'd what you described with FireFox. With Chrome, hitting "enter" in the location bar still caused a 304. I found going to another page (e.g. google.com) and then hitting the back button would show the cache behavior as desired. (Interestingly, if I got to my page via the "forward" button it ALWAYS displayed the cached file.)

Comment: Thanks, that is good info on Chrome. I guess the main thing to do if you are testing is to try to simulate whatever your users do, whatever combination of clicking links, clicking bookmarks (direct traffic) that is, which you can estimate from the referer data (I would guess that these would both load from valid cache). And break down by browser. Or just trust Firefox/Chrome and be happy that you are implementing HTTP correctly the way you want.

Comment: So, when testing how browser caching works (in Chrome at least) open the desired URL in a new tab, then you can go to some new url and then hit back. Using ENTER in address line and certainly F5 results in hard reload for me.

Comment: Someone got an answer to this? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964948/force-browser-to-send-always-if-none-match-when-max-age-is-expired-but-was-i