# Does If-None-Match header overrules Cache-Control: max-age?

Tags: playframework, cache-control, etag, if-none-match

I have a webapp that serves an image:

[image]

I'm clearly setting the `Cache-Control` header properly, and the web server is setting the `Etag`.

The problem is that **the resources is being `If-None-Match`ed every single time** effectively ignoring the `Cache-Control` header. (The framework is returning 304 accordingly but the roundtrip exists).

[I've read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19535835/7595) that the `Etag` header may overrule `Cache-Control` and still go to check the match even if the resource is local and valid. This makes no sense to me.

Anyone knows what's going on? What am I missing here?

PD: The web server is a Play! application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got it. Some browsers (Google Chrome and Firefox for sure) ignore the local cache when you reload the page with CMD+R or F5.

In my case, no matter how high I set the max-age, a page reload will always force the `If-None-Match` check and get a 304 back. Navigating through the website by clicking links will not trigger this behaviour and caches will work just fine.

Note: I didn't noticed this since in a single page webapp (like mine) there's no "link clicking navigation", since most of them are loaded at the beginning.

Comment: If anybody will read this: Today's version of Chrome (57.x) does send `max-age:0` and `If-None-Match` even on hitting the `Enter` key in the browser URL... The same as it works when hitting `F5`. So the caching could not be tested this way anymore. See [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557251/why-does-browser-still-sends-request-for-cache-control-public-with-max-age/19535835#comment73646392_19535835).

Answer (score 2):

You may be getting hit by proxies.

The `max-age` directive is intended for browsers, while the `s-maxage` directive is intended for proxies.

You seem to be missing the s-maxage directive in your Cache-Control header.

You may also want to add the [`public` directive](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1). (even though according to the specification this should be the default, it doesn't hurt to set it explicitly)

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3

Also, keep in mind that some proxies could very well choose to ignore all this, so you won't stop receiving requests completely even if you have everything perfectly configure on you end.

I have all 3 directives set in a service that serves images (that also uses ETag and Last-Modified) for a CDN and I haven't noticed abnormal behaviour in my tests.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Forgot to mention that this is hapenning even in my dev machine, on localhost and obviously no proxies involved.

Comment: here's the bounty. Thanks for taking the time to provide an answer.